# creating custom leaflet marker on map with idxbroker code

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, marker, idx

I created a real estate website that uses a company called idxbroker to handle the data from the mls (multiple listing service). I want to have a custom marker to populate on the map for property listings that I have personally so that they stand out when someone searches for properties. Idxbroker does this, however, the marker they provide for my personal listings has a tiny star inside of the same marker used for all listings and you wouldn't realize it unless you were looking for it. I know how to create a custom marker based on leaflet doc's, but not sure how to implement this since idxbroker hosts all this data from their server on my custom subdomain. Is there a way to inject javascript into their code so that my listings have a custom marker?[general marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h41OG.png) & [marker for my listings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6fy3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to add a custom marker on a results page or on the details pages?

It might be easier to just hide the IDX map and write your own in it's place with your custom marker.

Can you provide a map code sample or a link to the page you are trying to customize?